# php soap fatal Error but i want the error from the webservices

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap

I have a soap connection established, I need to give the webservice a key to get the methodes working. But if i give a wrong key it gives me a Fatal Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Client] Wrong apiKey in
```

But I need the go "past" this fatal error and get the error from the webservice it self. Because it has a build in Error class for if the key is wrong.

This is the code I use:

```
    try{
$client = new SoapClient("http://portal.webservice.com/AccountService.svc?singleWsdl");
}

Catch(exception $e){
$response = $client->CheckUserCridentialsValid(array(
                            "apiKey" => "$key",
                            "userName" => "$username",
                            "password" => "$password"));

    if($response->CheckUserCridentialsValidResult) {
        $response_model = $client->Account(array(
                            "apiKey" => "$key",
                            "userName" => "$username"));

        $_SESSION['AccountID']  = $response_model->AccountResult->AccountID;
        $_SESSION['UserName']   = $username;
        redirect_to('index.php');

    } else {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message = "Username or Password incorrect! <br>";
        redirect_to('welcome.php');
}}
```

The script will not get past the line where `"apiKey" => "$key",`.
So I never reach the point were I can get a error from the webservice. I build in a try and catch, but then the I just get a blank page and no redirect with a message.

Comment: Does the distributor of the web service provide a test case ? If so, check your key is valid for real. Also try to replace  `"apiKey" => "$key"` by  `"apiKey" => $key` same as userName and password. Also look out whether there are other log messages like WARN (maybe change the debug level). I

Comment: yeah have the valid key. And everything is working like it should. Only if i give a invalid key. I get this fatal error, I know the person that created the webservices. But he only knows C#, he told me that I should catch the exception and then get the Error from his class he build in to the  webservice. I dont even know if this is possible with PHP.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think [this] could help you. It is german, but the code will show you how to handle try catch with soap.

Comment: oh - sorry - it doesn't accept it for some reason: https://www.tutorials.de/threads/uncaught-soapfault-exception-ohne-begruendung-bei-einfachem-logon.363296/